APCI BIOS error (bug) could not resolve
I use a Lenovo Ideapad S340 with dual boot with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and windows 11. I have been using this dual boot configuration for a long time.
I switched off and then rebooted. I was charging my Huawei watch, and I am getting error as following:

Original Image Source

This question is similar to: ACPI error on every boot. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
